# Crypto Currency with decred Coin through the RPC and wallet

Tags: express

In decred coin I am trying
to manage decred coin such as get balance by address or send/receive coin.
But I am using node rpc decred package. But It's not working anything. 
I have no idea.

```
var dcrd = new dcrcoin.Client({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 19109, // testnet default port 
  user: '',
  pass: '',
  ssl: true
  //,sslCa: fs.readFileSync('~/.dcrd/rpc.cert') 
});
```

When I run this code It's shown 'unable connect the server' 
Please solve this problem. 
Thanks. 
Tian yang

Comment: `host: '127.0.0.1'` means it's trying to connect to a server on your local machine.

Comment: Yes. So I have also install the local server for decred wallet but. that's not working

Comment: You should have an rpcuser and rpcpassword to give it. Look at your dcrwallet config.  You also will need to use the correct cert. If connecting to the wallet, you need the rpc.cert for the wallet.